# Using google API to get lat&long from address in PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-maps

I m curently Using google geocode API to get LatLong from Address but it not display result correctly .Please tell whats wrong in my code .Thanks in advance.

Code :

```
            $address1=$this->input->post("Deal_Address1")."<br>";
            $address2=$this->input->post("Deal_Address2")."<br>";
            $CompleteAddress=$address1."".$address2."<br>"; 
            $address=str_replace(' ','+',$CompleteAddress);
            $address=str_replace(',','+',$address);
            $url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=$address&sensor=false&region=Israel";
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, 3128);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
            $response = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            $response_a = json_decode($response);
            //var_dump($response_a);
            if(isset($response_a->results[0])>0){
             $latitude = $response_a->results[0]->geometry->location->lat."<br>";
             $longitude = $response_a->results[0]->geometry->location->lng."<br>"; }else{
                 $latitude=0.00;
                 $longitude=0.00;
            }



$url=http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=32+Lehi+Street+Jerusalem&sensor=false®ion=Israel
```

Get Result In ARRAY : `object(stdClass)#19 (2) { ["results"]=> array(0) { } ["status"]=> string(12) "ZERO_RESULTS" }`

Comment: Why is there a "®" symbol in your $url?  And why isn't it quoted?

Comment: Its automatically converted I don't know why ?

Comment: seems to work fine for me using the $url provided..

Comment: @Sudhir yes it work fine when we remove ® from false®ion .can you please tell from where i get this sign ?

Answer (score 0):

Dont care about the ® , it will be displayed by the browser when dumping the $url, because he expects a character-reference when a ampersand is used, and will accidently resolve `&region`.

Remove the trailing `<br>`'s from `$CompleteAddress`, `$address1` and `$address2` .

Comment: Maybe you are not able to transpose my suggestion? [Your faulty code](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/djv-m9c) -> [my suggestion](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/jf5-yz7)